# How do alpha particles heat the plasma in tokamaks and what does that trajectory look like?

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-fields, nuclear-physics, collision, fusion

In a tokamak, a toroid with toroidal and poloidal magnetic fields, Deuterium and Tritium (D-T) fuse at ~10 keV to produce an alpha particle (3.5 MeV) and neutron (14.1 MeV).

The magnetic fields confine the charged particles to move in gyrations (Larmor orbits) around the toroidal magnetic field lines. The alpha particles are supposed to interact with the plasma of D-T particles, heating them further, leading to self-sustaining fusion.

In this fusion reaction, I suspect that half of the alpha particles will move in the negative direction of the plasma current, effectively cooling down the plasma just as much as it heats it. All of the literature claims that the alpha particles contribute 3.5 MeV to heat the plasma, so could someone clarify what I am missing?

Comment: Since the alpha particles represent fusion "ash", I'm wondering how they are removed from the plasma.  For any responders, I would appreciate you including that detail in your answer.

Comment: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0029-5515/40/1/307

Comment: this earlier https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0029-5515/40/1/307/pdf

Comment: @WillWillCUB  "I suspect that half of the alpha particles will move in the negative direction of the plasma current," this is wrong, the charge of the alpha does not change!

Comment: @annav I guess I meant that in the fusion reaction, the resulting particles will fly off in all directions. Some of the alphas will move with velocity parallel to the directions that the Deuterium and Tritium are moving. Some of the alphas will move in the opposite direction. The ones moving in the opposite direction will presumably slow down any ions they collide with. This is what I'm confused about still. 

I will do some calculations, but maybe there is a solution in considering that heating occurs via electron-ion collision, and that the alpha particles move slower than the electrons.

Comment: The alpha particles have a charge of +2,   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle they are ions and have to follow the rest of the  positive ions of the plasma. that they might get a random momentum perpendicular to the plasma current will just give a  spread in that direction

Comment: @annav The problem is that half of the alphas will initially move with some velocity opposite to that of the rest of the positive ions. Tke two extreme cases: D-T fuse and create an alpha and neutron. Case 1 the alpha is shot off perfectly parallel to the D-T ions and therefore transfers all its energy to them. Case 2 the alpha is shot off perfectly opposite to the D-T ions and therefore slows them down, or at least sends the ions in the opposite direction as well. The magnetic field is used to keep ions flowing in one direction, but not the other.

Comment: The instantaneous momentum of the creation of alpha will be overcome by the magnetic field created forces on the positive charge, there is no *flow*

Comment: @annav If that were true then you're claiming that the 3.5 MeV of the alpha is negated by the magnetic field, and that there is no heating. And there is flow, which is what the plasma current is. The plasma current, mediated by the FLOW of electrons and ions, gives rise to poloidal fields.

Comment: Your kinematics is wrong, Energy is always conserved, you just need the proper maths

Comment: @annav That doesn't really help, unless you point out where I was wrong. Nowhere did I say energy is not conserved.

Answer (score 1):

Alphas heat the plasma by slowing down through kinetic energy transfer.
It is a Coulomb collision problem of 2 moving particles.
The slowing down equation is established from the coefficients of friction and diffusion of a fast ion of velocity V interacting with an ionic and electronic population of velocity v.

The "ashes" which are a mixture of helium, fuel and impurities coming from the walls, are recovered in the edge zone of the plasma in traps which neutralize them, then they are pumped, sorted and reinjected for some: this is active pumping, and by the way, it helps to control the fuel content of the plasma.